# How to print Java array values with one particular id?

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I have one array with values but I want to print the values with id that mean`{"id":1}` My array with values are

```
int[] arr={1,2,3,4,5};
```

I want to print output values like below

```
{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5}
```

Is it possible in Java?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to print output in Java.  What have you tried?  What isn't working?

Comment: int[] myIntArray = {1,2,3};
        
    for(int i=0;i<myIntArray.length;i++){
        
        System.out.println("{'id':"+myIntArray[i]+"}");
        
         }

Comment: And how is that code not doing what you expect?  What is the problem you've encountered?  Be specific, nobody here can see your screen.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow :

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};

    String id = "\"id\"";

    for(int i = 0 ; i <=arr.length; i++){

        System.out.println("{"+id+": " + arr[i] + "}");
    }
```

Comment: You do it now ?

Comment: i don't know please help me if you know

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array and just

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
for(int a : arr){
  System.out.println("{id:" + a + "}");
}
```

Where "a" is a short life variable that takes the value of each element in the array "arr"

This way you can print {id:1} with this short code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to do it in recent Java versions (8 or higher)

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.stream(arr) // stream over int array
          .mapToObj(i -> "{\"i\":" + i + "}") // convert int to custom String
          .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) // join Strings using a comma
) // print the big string
```